# Watir can't locate frame which houses an element in Firefox but works fine in IE

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

I have a script:

```
BROWSER.frame( :name, 'FRAME_NAVIGATION' ).span(:text=>'foo').fire_event('onmouseup')
```

which clicks on elements of a tree view (inside a frame) which works great in IE, but when I set:

```
require 'watir'
Watir::Browser.default = 'firefox'
```

and run it I get:

```
Failure/Error: 
BROWSER.frame( :name, 'FRAME_NAVIGATION').span(:text=>'foo').fire_event('onmouseup')
Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException:
Unable to locate a frame using name and FRAME_NAVIGATION.
```

I get this with any elements inside a frame on my page. Not just the tree view. I've tried requiring firewatir as well, or just on its own with no luck.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

-M

Comment: is it possible to get a copy of the page/frame source?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm doing this for work, and my NDA prohibits that sort of thing. If you tell me what you're looking for, I may be able to cut it and and change any proprietary bits.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the frame method correctly. Try this way:

```
BROWSER.frame(:name => 'FRAME_NAVIGATION').span(:text => 'foo').fire_event('onmouseup')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to diagnose the problem by adding a BROWSER.show_frames call.  That would tell you what Firefox thinks it can see.